# Prove equation using Bernoulli's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality

How do I show that $\forall a,b\in \Bbb R |a>0\land b>0$ and $\forall n \in \Bbb N$ $$a^nb\le (\frac{na+b}{n+1})^{n+1}$$ Using the Bernoulli's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality can be rewritten as:

$$(\frac{(n+1)a+b-a}{n+1})^{n+1}=(\frac{b-a}{n+1}+a)^{n+1}=a^{n+1}(\frac{b-a}{a(n+1)}+1)^{n+1} \geq a^{n+1}(1+\frac{b-a}{a})=a^nb$$

You can also make use of AM-GM inequality:

$$(\frac{na+b}{n+1})^{n+1}=(\frac{a+a+...+a+b}{n+1})^{n+1}\geq (\sqrt[n+1]{a^nb})^{n+1}=a^nb$$

Because $a$ appears $n$ times in the second term.